# Real time video processing from camera

Tags: matlab, real-time, video-processing

I have a problem with real time video processing.
I want to access consequent frames (previous, current & next).

```
...
trigger(RawVideo)
cur_frame=getdata(RawVideo,1,'uint8');
imshow(cur_frame);
...
```

I can't access previous or next frame from this code though.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're processing in "real time" you won't have access to the *next* frame. As for the previous frame, you'll have to create a buffer to store it in so when you process the current frame you may reference it. You could also make two buffers (the last two previous frames) and call the first previous frame "current", the current frame "next", and the second previous frame "previous". Maybe that helps?

Comment: How to store a frame in memory? Just assign them to a different variable: `prev_frame_2 = prev_frame_1; prev_frame_1 = cur_frame; cur_frame = getdata(RawVideo,1,'uint8');`. Now at any time after frame 3 you have access to current frame, previous frame, and previous frame 2. Make sure you initialize those variables at the beginning of your code: `prev_frame_1 = []; prev_frame_2 = [];` or if you know the size of the frame: `prev_frame_1 = zeros(size_h, size_w); prev_frame_2 = prev_frame_1;`

Comment: I think it does not work , Do you have another way to get consequent frames?

Comment: @Bayanaa: If it doesn't work post the code you tried and we'll try to help you from there.

Comment: for num = 1: frame_lim
            trigger(RawVideo);
            prev_frame_1 = []; 
            prev_frame_2 = [];
            prev_frame_3 = [];
            cur_frame    = [];
            
            cur_frame  = getdata(RawVideo,1,'uint8'); 
            prev_frame_1 = cur_frame;
            prev_frame_2 = prev_frame_1;
            prev_frame_3 = prev_frame_2;
   
            myfunction(prev_frame_2,cur_frame);
end